# Using Not In with a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
select *
from    Table1 tb1
where   ((tb1.Field1 + tb1.Field2 + tb1.Field3) not in
        (
            select  (tb2.Field1 + tb2.Field2 + tb2.Field3)
            from    Table2 tb2          )
    )
```

The query runs in about 10 seconds on sql server 2000, but on sql server 2005 it runs for hours. The machines are identical and both environments have the same keys and indexes.
Each table has about 350,000 records. The only thing I can think of is sql2005 doesn't handle the concatenations the same. 
I am working on an upgrade to sql2005 (haha, I wish it would be to 2008 or 2012 but that is out of my control). Any Ideas would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Please post the execution plans (or at least the estimated execution plans) for both queries.

Comment: Are the index statistics current on both systems?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 tb1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    table2 tb2
        WHERE   tb2.field1 = tb1.field1
                AND tb2.field2 = tb1.field2
                AND tb3.field3 = tb1.field3
        )
```

This would work on both databases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write the query like this in both databases:

```
select tb1.*
from Table1 tb1 left outer join
     Table2 tb2
     on tb1.Field1 = tb2.Field1 and
        tb1.Field2 = tb2.Field2 and
        tb1.Field3 = tb3.Field3
where tb2.Field1 is null;
```

Then, if this doesn't perform well, you can even add an index on `Table2(Field1, Field2, Field3)` and/or `Table1(Field1, Field2, Field3)` to improve performance.

(Note:  I am assuming that the concatenation is to ensure that the individual fields are the same.  That is, you don't have a situation like ('A', 'B', 'C') in one table and ('ABC', '', '') in the other.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN